# Tkinter Canvas must be initialized before its contents. Is it a feature or a bug?

Tags: python, tkinter, tk-toolkit

I just came across a strange behavior of `Tkinter` when debugging my program. If a `Frame` object is created before a `Canvas` object and later inserted into that `Canvas`, it can't be displayed. However if the creation order is inverted (firstly `Canvas` and then `Frame`), contents in the `Frame` is displayed correctly.

For example, the following code works well:

```
from Tkinter import *

app = Frame()
canvas = Canvas(app)
frame = Frame(app)
Label(frame, text = 'aaaa').pack()
Label(frame, text = 'bbbb').pack()
canvas.create_window(0, 0, anchor = NW, window = frame)
canvas.grid()
app.grid()
app.mainloop()
```

But if the initialization order is inverted, like:

```
frame = Frame(app)
canvas = Canvas(app)
```

you get nothing but a blank window.

Is this a intentionally designed behavior (If so, why?), or I just found a bug in `Tkinter`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a feature. Widgets have a stacking order that defaults to the order that they were created. You can adjust this stacking order with the `lift` and `lower` methods.

For example, you can create the frame first and then the canvas, so that the canvas has a higher stacking order. As you observe, you don't see the frame because it is behind the canvas. To make it visible, you can `lift` it:

```
frame.lift(canvas)
```

Doing so will give the same visual effect as if you had created the canvas first.

This technique can be useful to hide and show widgets. For example, you can create a notebook-like widget by stacking several frames on top of each other, and then using `lift` to bring the one you want to be visible to the top of the order.

Comment: If you're using this to hide/reveal widgets, be aware that it has no effect on focus handling. It's easy to end up with an invisible widget having the keyboard focus, which is… _rather strange_ from a user's perspective…